# I'm losing data on the way Controller-View-Controller. How right get Model from View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the Model which contains the few properties. There are `List<Point>` and `ThranslatingCam`. The `ThranslatingCam` contains property which should be entered by the user.

```
public class TranslatingCamModel
{
   public TranslatingCam Cam { get; set; }
   public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use the `Points` just for visualization but in future this list will be changed by user.

In the Controller I initialize the `Points` list, add it to my `TranslatingCamModel` and send it to the View.

```
public ActionResult Cam()
{
   TranslatingCamModel model = new TranslatingCamModel();
   List<Points> points = new List<Points>();

   //here I add same data to the points list

   model.Points = points;
   model.Cam = new TranslatingCam();

   return View("TranslatingCam", model);
}
```

This code works as I want. My problem is further.

```
@model CamShaft.WebUI.Models.TranslatingCamModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cam";
}

<div class="prop">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DrawTranslatingCam", "Home"))
    {
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cam.Rmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cam.Rmin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      //And the same for the other Cam's properties
      <input type="submit" value="Draw" />
    }
</div>
//Here is my code for visualization and etc... And here I can work with the model.Points.
```

It works okay too, I get value for `Cam` but I lose my `Points` list.

```
public ActionResult DrawTranslatingCam(TranslatingCamModel model)
{
    //Here I have model returned from the View
}
```

Here is `model.Cam` with entered by user data but `model.Points` list is `null`. But I initialized it before I sent it to the View..

I tried to solve using `@Html.HiddenFor`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DrawTranslatingCam", "Home"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cam.Rmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cam.Rmin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    //And the same for the other Cam's properties

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Points)
    <input type="submit" value="Draw" />
    }
```

In this case is returned `Points` list but without date (not `null`, just with count = 0)

**So, how right I can get my Model from the View?**

*The code has been slightly modified for compactness and clarity.*

Comment: Unless you generate inputs for each property of each `Points` in the collection, then you can't. A form only posts back the name/vale pairs of its successful controls. Just get the collection again in the POST method if you need it again

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I update question. What do you think about smth like `@Html.HiddenFor`?

Comment: I asked the question when there was little activity here. And now I do not know how to up the question :(

Comment: If you inspect the `value` attribute that generates you will understand why that can never work :) Again, _Just get the collection again in the POST method if you need it again_! (it is just crazy, and degrading performance, and opening your self to attacks by malicious users to generate inputs for each property of each item in a collection that is not even being edited)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , okay, I got you. **Thanks for your answer** :)